# Automation testing in android

Tags: android, automated-tests

can anyone knows how to send email after the test cases passed? I am using automation tool Robotium. and I write test cases for Login. once all test are passed. I want to send the email and that email contains the test report  of test cases i.e it is passed or failed how to do that?

Comment: This may help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850641/how-to-generate-test-result-report-using-robotium]

Comment: I think it could be useful to assembly a continuous integration environment in this case. You can use JenkinsIC for instance, build a job to run your automated tests and, at end of that, you can configure the job to send e-mails. Jenkis is free and fairly easy to use